# Pulp not find solution

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

i am trying find optimal solution of problem using Pulp module in Python. My problem  is on photo. I wrote this problem in Pulp but I get that this problem is Infeasible (status -1). I know that this problem have solution but I must make some mistake in code (when I change that variables are continuous problem has continuous solution).
Thank you for your help.

```
import numpy as np
# Import PuLP modeler functions
from pulp import *

# Creates the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Computer company service problem", LpMinimize )
demand = {1: 6000, 2: 7000, 3: 8000, 4: 9500, 5: 11500}

# A dictionary called 'Vars' is created to contain the referenced variables(the routes)
vars_x = LpVariable.dicts("x", range(1,6), 0, None, LpInteger)
vars_y = LpVariable.dicts("y", range(1,6), 0, None, LpInteger)

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([15000*vars_y[i] + 7500*vars_x[i]  for i in range(1,6)]), "Sum_of_employee_cost"

# The demand minimum constraints are added to prob for each demand
for i in range(1,6):
    prob += 160*vars_y[i]-50*vars_x[i]>=demand[i], f"Reach demand in month {i}"
    
# The demand minimum constraints are added to prob for each demand node (bar)
prob += vars_y[1]==50, f"Workers in month {1}" 


for i in range(2,6):
    prob += 0.95*vars_y[i-1]+vars_x[i-1]==vars_y[i], f"Workers in month {i}" 


prob.solve()
```

[image]

Comment: I think your last constraint should be a `>=` although I admit I haven't read the text completely. At least you get a solution that way.

Comment: As @pchtsp has suggested you need to change the last constraint. You have integer variables `vars_y` and `vars_x` to represent number of technicians and trainees. However the last constraint will result in non-integer values on the right-hand-side. Would suggest you re-write as `vars_y[i] <= 0.95*vars_y[i-1]+vars_x[i-1]`. This will ensure at least enough trainees coming through (5% are lost on average - but it may be more some months and some trainees might not make it to be full technicians).